# What to See Trace Logs for Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core, azure-app-service-plans

Using `.NET Core 2` in `Azure App Service`. Don't see my logs. In the actual application, the logging code looks like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Trace.WriteLine("Logging works");
```

I expected to see the `Trace` logs in the `Log Stream`, but I don't. I do see general API logs. What am I doing wrong? My config below:

[image: p]

Comment: Check if auto flush setting is set to false (in your code / config)

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Where would that be? In the app config on Azure or in the C# solution?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=netcore-2.1

Comment: It's defaulted to false as per your link and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.autoflush?view=netframework-4.8. Also, ty.

Comment: Try set it to true

Comment: Trying `Trace.Flush();` right after the test trace would work too, right?

Comment: That didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue for .NET core azure web app: Trace.WriteLine method does not work(not write message to Application logs) for .NET core, but work for .NET framework , and I find the [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/39611) about that.

As a workaround for .NET core web application, I suggest you can use ILogger, which can write message to `Application Logs`.

In `Startup.cs` -> `Configure` method, re-write `Configure` method like below:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
           //your other code

            //add the following 2 lines of code.
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();


            app.UseStaticFiles();

            //your other code
}
```

Then in HomeController.cs, add the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger; 

    public HomeController(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<HomeController>();
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("this is a information from ILogger...");

        return View();
    }

    //other code

  }
```

After publish to azure, and configure the Application Logging -> run the azure web app -> you can see the message is displayed in Application Logs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Ivan. I will try that this weekend.